# How to prevent multiple posts on MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> A user wants to post in his blog, he fills the field and click `submit`.
>
> The site is running slow, he clicks again, and again, and again.
>
> It was finally saved, but now he check his posts and sees `4` posts.

**How can I prevent this from happening?** If the user click to submit once I want to `do nothing` for the next clicks or `abort previous` and start a new post, whichever makes more sense or is recommended.

In a form with

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
{
}
```

Comment: do nothing or abort previous and start new ones

Comment: @hunter Yes I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to disable submit buttons after click.

Add the following javascript (jQuery) to your view:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Remember to enable buttons after ajax request complete if neccessary:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

UPDATE:

It's better to disable the submit button in forms submit event handler, because an user can submit the form by pressing enter button:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: This will prevent the post to be submitted **even when** the click genuinely did not succeed. I prefer `server-side` check.

Comment: @Aliostad: also a good point. My answer affects only user interface and not protects from multiple requests.

Comment: There is a similar question and answer which also uses JQuery but takes into account if the form is valid... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080360/prevent-multiple-form-submits-in-mvc-3-with-validation

Comment: Setting `disabled` seemed to not call my `btnSubmit_Click()` handler so I'm using `.hide()` instead. Are there any drawbacks you guys can think of by using `hide()` instead of `disabled`? I'm still doing some server side checking with Session, but always like to not hit the server when not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions.

> One is to create a random `GUID` with
>   the form as a hidden field which is
>   inserted into database with the post.
>   Before inserting, it checks if `GUID`
>   already exists.

Alternatively you can use a real property such as DateTime (which is sent to the client side as a hidden field) or "Post title".

Answer (score 0):

How about the minute the user clicks on the action link for the post area you create a real post but set its "Status" to draft?. After you InsertOnSubmit() the post immediately redirect to an action which you retrieve the post and edit it. This happens so fast the user will not notice. So if the site is slow and he clicks on "Submit" multiple times you will not be generating new records just saving to the same record. I using the process on an task list application I working on. See the code below.

[Better Task List Ticket Controller](http://code.google.com/p/better-task-list-1-1-progress/source/browse/trunk/Areas/Projects/Controllers/TicketController.cs)

It may not be the fanciest solution but could lead you to a more creative solution that works for you.

Comment: the link you have provided is no more

Comment: Thanks for the heads up john, I fixed the URL.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for ActionFilters. [This blog post](http://rionghost.azurewebsites.net/2013/02/24/prevent-repeated-requests-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/) has code to just drop into your project and decorate your actions.