# Prevent multiple form submits in MVC 3 with validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form with many input fields on it, some with validation. I use the default validation plugin in MVC 3. If the server response is slow, the user may click to submit another time, which may cause undesired behavior. How to prevent this? I've tried injecting code in the .submit event of the form, but this event is raised even if the validation fails.

Comment: Similar question with alternative answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869390/how-to-prevent-multiple-posts-on-mvc3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could check whether validation succeeded and disable the submit button:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```